# How do I find the maximum value of a given variable from my dataset using the "max" function?

Tags: r, function, variables, max

Forgive me for being ignorant but Im trying to find the max value of the "ID" in my dataset.

```
str (mvtweek1)
'data.frame':   191641 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ ID                 : int  8951354 8951141 8952745 8952223 8951608 8950793 8950760 8951611 8951802 8950706 ...
 $ Date               : Factor w/ 131680 levels "1/1/01 0:01",..: 42824 42823 42823 42823 42822 42821 42820 42819 42817 42816 ...
 $ LocationDescription: Factor w/ 78 levels "ABANDONED BUILDING",..: 72 72 62 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 ...
 $ Arrest             : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
 $ Domestic           : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ Beat               : int  623 1213 1622 724 211 2521 423 231 1021 1215 ...
 $ District           : int  6 12 16 7 2 25 4 2 10 12 ...
 $ CommunityArea      : int  69 24 11 67 35 19 48 40 29 24 ...
 $ Year               : int  2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 ...
 $ Latitude           : num  41.8 41.9 42 41.8 41.8 ...
 $ Longitude          : num  -87.6 -87.7 -87.8 -87.7 -87.6 ...
```

1. Using max how do I do first find the maximum value of the variable "ID"
2. How do I find How many observations have value TRUE in the Arrest variable
3. How do I find how many observations have a LocationDescription value of ALLEY?
4. What function do I need to use in R to extract the date and time.
5. Where can I find a simple list of these commands and their functions.  For example I found max() in the manual but it didn't work as explained when I tried to find the variable for "ID".

Again I'm just starting out and had a difficult time just figuring out how to load the dataset correctly.  I had no idea I need to add the command header=T.  Is there a tutorial for this?

thx

Comment: What exactly didn't work as expected? `max(mvtweek1$ID)` should work as expected, there is absolutely no reason not to. For second question `sum(mvtweek1$Arrest)` will do. For third, do `sum(mvtweek1$LocationDescription == "ALLEY")`. For fourth, look into `?as.Date` and `?strptime`.

Comment: Regarding your last question, I like ucla's tutorials: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/raw_data.htm Stackoverflow isn't really the right place to ask for tutorials, and when you *do* have a real question, you should ask one question at a time, not six.

Comment: When I tried to use max(mvtweek1$ID) I got this message = Error: unexpected '$' in "max(mvtweek1,$"

Comment: You copied the command wrong by putting a comma before the dollar sign.

Comment: also sum(mvtweek1$Arrest) give me 15536 which is a wrong answer for TRUE variable

Comment: Who said it's wrong? `sum(mvtweek1$Arrest)` should give you the correct answer. Try this on a dummy data, for example: `df <- data.frame(A = c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)) ; sum(df$A)`

Comment: You can just copy/paste instead manually typing...

Comment: this gave me the correct answer sum(mvtweek1$Arrest == "TRUE")

Comment: and format(mvtweek1$Date) gave me what I was looking for although 91642 entries were omitted for some reason.  "max.print" To much data perhaps?

Comment: Next I used the dateconvert "as.Date(strptime(mvtweek1$Date, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))" to find the month day and year but now I need to find the median date?  When I tried median(strptime(mvtweek1$Date, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))  I got a N?A answer.  What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: I also tried median(format(mvtweek1$Date)) and got 4/10/09 but it says thats the wrong answer

Comment: I tried median(as.Date(strptime(mvtweek1$Date, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")))
and it worked

Comment: Ok Im now trying to extract the month and the day of the week, and add these variables to the data frame mvtweek1.using "mvtweek1$Month" which works fine and "mvtweek!$Weekday" which keeps giving me a "NULL" answer.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should consider creating a new question on SO when you have something new to ask, rather than posting comments on your first question.

Comment: Marc, please remember that it's against the 15.071x course policy to ask for answers to homework questions on forums -- this applies not just to the course discussion forum but also to places like StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank for letting me know that josilber.  I am only monitoring the class  but I will respect the rules.  I'll try to find another way to figure out why I can't get functions to work . Hard to teach an old dog new tricks.  I do really like this site and you are all welcome to check out my website which is totally free and no email needed to view all the content there.  The link is on my profile page here.

Comment: Thanks. If it helps, there is working code in the explanation of every homework problem.

Comment: I have to apologize to you all.  I did not recognize the tab at the top of the page for the class I am monitoring.  I only watched the introduction video and thought perhaps the instructor wanted me to research R on my own and figure out how to write function scrips from the manual or something.  It was only after I went back to the homework page that I finally stumbled upon the other videos that instructed me how to get these answers.  I was not trying to cheat the exam I was just flying blind.  Forgive my stupidity.  I can only hope 15.071x doesn't expel me for asking you for help here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing some nuance in the question, but here is how I would approach these.

Finding the max:

```
maxID <- max(mvtweek1$ID)
```

How many rows in which Arrest is TRUE:

```
arrestCount <- nrow(mvtweek1[mvtweek1$Arrest==TRUE,])
```

How many locations are alleys:

```
numAlley <- nrow(mvtweek1[mvtweek1$LocationDescription=="ALLEY",])
```

In order to convert to date, please see this link on [strptime](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/strptime).

Comment: Better not to link to external resources when possible (since the links may be dead some time in the future). In this case, you could refer to `help("strptime")` or `?strptime`.

Answer (score 0):

aggregate(mvtweek1$ID, function(x) max(x))